# I am getting comma(,) separated data but i want it row by row with that particular id for each individual row?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql-9.3, psql

I am getting data into my database as comma(,) separated as shown in first pic.

**comma separated data**

[image]

I want to insert that data as following format shown in second pic

**row by row data with that id**

[image]

**My requirement :** I need an insert statement to get the output as shown in the picture2. For that I have used select query to get the picture2 format which I need.
But, now I need INSERT statement for that instead of SELECT statement.

Comment: Which database you are using? Please don't tag products which you are not involved.

Comment: share your select statement..

Comment: Great. Pictures of data (rather than text) so we can have fun transcribing it manually (rather than Copy & Paste), and you want help converting a working `SELECT` statement into an `INSERT`, but you're not even *showing* us the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question not clear but still I am trying to answer, hope it helps:

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM other_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

once I also tried for the same I wrote a programming query! use this query in your db.it may work for you.

```
insert into twitter_entities(E_hashtags_position0_text,hashtags_position_indices_indices0, hashtags_position_indices_indices1)values(regexp_split_to_table(?,','),?,?)";
```